# Execute binary with parameters located inside addon folder

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, kango-framework

I am using kango framework - http://kangoextensions.com/docs/index.html and would like to execute a binary (with CLI arguments) located inside my addon folder. The examples shared here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=446245 does not work probably because I am not using the Firefox-Addon framework and errors our with

`The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.`

followed by `TypeError: Components.classes is undefined` My question is how to execute the binary in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964229/run-a-linux-command-with-firefox-sdk

Comment: which method did you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27964566/235887

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Components` use [`require("chrome")` click here for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority)